# How do I assign jQuery slider handle values with their left or right edges, instead of their centers?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm playing with jQuery UI, and I've discovered something disappointing about their multi-handle slider implementation.

I've made an example for you here. I've made the handles slightly transparent so you can see what's going on:

https://codepen.io/ophello/pen/BaNaPdp

The first slider has the handles centered normally. When you click and drag them so they collide, **they overlap**. Gross!

Below that one, I made duplicate slider, except for this one, I've used CSS to adjust the margins of the handle positions so they don't collide, and **they butt up right against each other** when they meet, just like two physical sliders would! Great!

```
#mySlider2 .ui-slider-handle:first-child {
  margin-left: -12px !important;
}

#mySlider2 .ui-slider-handle:last-child {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}
```

But... the problem is that by messing with the margins of these elements, the cursor drag position is now *outside the handle.* Try dragging the bottom left slider and you'll see what I mean. When you start to drag it, it jumps to fit the new drag point, which is not in the center of the handle anymore.

I need to somehow get the handle's clickable area to be the handle boundary itself, but have the handle's *returned value* for the UI slider to correspond to the handle's *right* edge (or left edge for the other handle). Make sense?

I took a peek at the jquery slider.js and...it's impenetrably complex. Does anyone know if I can hack this to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I needed to add an offset value to both sliders, then subtract that value from the displayed result.

```
$(function() {

  var offset = 3;

  $("#mySlider").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: false,
    min: 0 - offset,
    step: 1,
    max: 100 + offset,
    values: [0 - offset, 100 + offset],
    slide: function(event, ui) {

      ui.values[0] = ui.values[0] + offset;
      ui.values[1] = ui.values[1] - offset;

      if (ui.values[0] >= (ui.values[1]) ) { return false; }

      $("#mySliderVal").val( ui.values[0]  + " – " + ui.values[1]);}

  });

  $("#mySliderVal").val(
    ($("#mySlider").slider("values", 0 ) + offset) + " – " +
    ($("#mySlider").slider("values", 1 ) - offset )
  );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is far from perfect yet it gets you a lot closer to what you were trying to achieve. If we make the `ui-slider-handle` a width of `0` or maybe even `1`, you now can use that as the exact counter point. You can push the handle out with `padding` in CSS to make it interact-able again.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mySlider").slider({
    classes: {
      "ui-slider": "collision"
    },
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    step: 1,
    max: 100,
    values: [0, 100],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1]) {
        return false;
      }
      $("#mySliderVal").val(ui.values[0] + " – " + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });

  var sldr = $("#mySlider").slider("widget");
  $(".ui-slider-handle:eq(0)", sldr).css({
    "padding-left": "8px",
    "margin-right": "-2px"
  });
  $(".ui-slider-handle:eq(1)", sldr).css({
    "padding-right": "8px",
    "margin-left": "-2px"
  });

  $("#mySliderVal").val(
    $("#mySlider").slider("values", 0) + " – " + $("#mySlider").slider("values", 1));
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input,
label {
  font-size: 13px;
}

div.ui-slider.collision {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div.ui-slider.collision .ui-slider-handle {
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 0;
}

div.ui-slider.collision .ui-slider-range {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="mySliderVal" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; text-align:left;width:75px">
  <div id="mySlider"></div>
</div>
```

Now you have a single slice for the handle and padding on the respective side, instead of from the center.

Comment: When I grab the left slider, the slider jumps outside where I'm dragging and is floating about 15px to the left of my mouse pointer. Not working :(